# how does the source file which in a symbol link folder to touch off a build action when it changed?

Tags: makefile, build, symlink, dpdk, ninja

I an working on VPP and DPDK, we know that in vpp when we `sudo make build` it will extract DPDK source code into ./build-root/build-vpp_debug-native/external/src-dpdk, then build DPDK and VPP.

- original behavoir: when I change any file in src-dpdk, and use `sudo make build`, it will build DPDK first，and link vpp again
- unexpect behavoir: I create a symbol link *`src-dpdk`* (by using ln -s ...) to instead the original `src-dpdk`, if we use `sudo make rebuild` command, it works well, and it build dpdk will use the right path that symbol link point to, **but when I do some change in real-path, then use `sudo make build`, the build seems can not perceive the source file change, so do not build DPDK again**, the build log will show **nothing to do**

**why I will use symbol link instead:** this is because in original vpp repository, the git can not track src-dpdk change, and for our project, we have a independend dpdk git repository, so I want link our dpdk instead the src-dpdk which created by vpp.

**additional:** vpp use make, and dpdk use ninja, meson

Answer (score 0):

First off, a makefile shouldn't use directories as targets/prerequisites, only files. These things and more happen when you do. The right way is listing any target or prerequisite files manually. Though sometimes using `wildcard` might work for you.

There are two other options for you that might work:

- Pass [-L/--check-symlink-times](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Options-Summary) to the make command: `sudo make -L build`
- In the makefile add a test whether that target is a symlink, and if it is add the target to [`.PHONY`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Phony-Targets).